# JavaCV cvCalcBackProject() result completely black

Tags: javacv

I have a histogram which I have normalized to 1.
When I backproject it the result is entirely black.

I saw the solution for OpenCV, but JavaCV doesn't allow scaling for backprojection, and doesn't overload it's cvNormalizeHist method to accept any other parameters other than histogram and double.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find examples of using cvCalcBackProject in the "OpenCV2 Cookbook" examples for JavaCV, [chapter 4](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples_Chapter_4). For instance, a simple one is in [Ex6ContentDetectionGrayscale](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/OpenCV2_Cookbook/src/opencv2_cookbook/chapter04/Ex6ContentDetectionGrayscale.scala?repo=examples&r=57c6b2e7c23b851924057fd69d9a33db1b4a4bd2).